# editing word document in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I am editing a word template and then saving it in on web server. for this i am using `Interop.Word` (i know this is bad but still...)

I have installed MS Word on server

Here is My code:

```
object fileName;
object saveAs;
fileName = Server.MapPath("~\\tempOutputs\\Template - Filled with Registration Data.docx");

try
{
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Word.Application wordApp =  new Word.Application();
Word.Document aDoc = null;
if (File.Exists((string)fileName))
{
    object readOnly = false;
    object isVisible = false;
    wordApp.Visible = false;

    aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing,
    ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing);

    aDoc.Activate(); //Error Line
```

I am getting error on `aDoc.Activate()` statement as `object reference not set to an instance` **But it works on my system**

Any suggestions ?

**EDIT**

I have wrote a console application using the code above and run it on server **it runs perfectly** then why not on IIS as web app ?

Comment: I have a feeling you need to have a server license for this to work... but I might be wrong. It might be useful to read up on OpenXML http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478255%28v=office.15%29.aspx ...but again, I might be wrong

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using the OOXML SDK?

Comment: We have Enterprise license for MS-Office which covers everything windows,email,office & so on

Comment: @Stilgar : i have put lot of efforts in `Interop` now cant go back again and start whole new thing ! plus it is almost delivery date :(

Comment: I can't remember where, but I'm pretty sure I've seen that trying to do any office automation on the server is considered to be a really BAD idea!

Comment: @freefaller Sagar states in his question he knows it's bad, but just being a bad idea doesn't normally stop it working.

Comment: @freefaller : i know ! i have figured out some alternatives also but dont have time to work on it now. if there is some setting which i can fix easily that would be good for now

Comment: @SagarDumbre, The error means that the aDocis not set to a document and it is null. Does the `fileName` you send as a parameter, is exist on the server as it was on your file system?

Comment: @user3165438 : Yes ! thats why it going inside loop

Comment: @SagarDumbre, what loop do you mean? When you debug, the aDoc is null?

Comment: @user3165438 : i mean this line `if (File.Exists((string)fileName))` btw i have also put logger on server it failing on activate line only

Comment: @SagarDumbre, OK, maybe it fails since the document is invisible and then you try to activate it?

Comment: @user3165438 : then how it works in my laptop ? i dont think its visibility issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58324/discussion-between-user3165438-and-sagar-dumbre).

Comment: Try to Check permissions on folder/directory where your word file is stored.

Comment: why do you want to `Activate` document? what if you remove this line- what next line will generate an error. I can't find any reason to `Activate`...

Comment: What versions of MS Word and Server OS do you have?

Comment: The file exists, but is it locked? Office in general isn't very friendly when it comes to sharing and that's one of the reasons why automation (of MS Office) on a server is a bad idea. A server is inherently going to be multithread and at some point two threads are going to try and open the same file and the whole thing will blow up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used VSTO long time ago maybe 7 or 8 years ago but not in server side... And it was painful I suffered a lot with stuck processes, memory leaks and strange problems my code worked somewhere and somewhere else not (like yours). 
The solution was that OS language and installed Office language not matched. So you should check that and also check your code culture info:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

If you really need VSTO (I can`t see why??) check the languages, install Office Language Pack, so on... but I also recommend to use something else.

Answer (score 1):

The whole approach is wrong.. 
Manipulating word documents on the server side should be done only using open xml or similar frameworks which are fundamentally designed to be working on a multi-threaded scenario.

Answer (score 1):

While the reasons you should not do this are legion (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757 for info), you may be running into a problem with who your code is running as.

What idenity is your webserver running as?  When you run interactively (i.e. debugging using visual studio, etc), you run as the currently logged in user, whereas on your server will be running as whoever the app pool that your webserver is running as (such as ApplicationPoolIdentity)

Answer (score 0):

Getting Word Interop running on the server side is mostly an issue of properly setting up the rights of the user account the app pool uses (e.g. webuser).

- read/write access to the respective folders
- actually login to the server using the webuser account and start Word; afterword disconnect; do not log out!
- add the webuser to the user group of "Distributed COM users"
- open component service administration and open the properties on MyComputer; In COM security give the user local start and local activate rights (should be redundant, but yeah)
- Open mmc (with '-32' if it's a 32Bit Word) and select "File" -> "Add/Remove snap in"; select component services on the left and click add and then ok; under computer/my computer search for "Microsoft Word 97 - 2003 document" and open the properties; enter the user under identity; under security add the user (if not there already) and give them the appropriate rights

That should do it settings-wise. That being said, server side word interop is still a pain in the rear side. We have it running pretty ok for 2 years on a production server now, but it wasn't without problems. I'm still not convinced it's really free of memory leaks either, even with all the load tests I ran on the test server. We only use it, because we need docx to pdf conversion and all libraries we tested either don't work properly, have terrible performance or use word interop as well. It runs as a discrete windows service with lots of hours that went into crash recovery etc. I'd never use it for editing documents. That's what the OpenXML SDK is for.

BTW: If your code doesn't end up riddled with finally blocks, you're definitely building in memory leaks. Also, you need to call `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` on the document you're using, the application's Documents property and the application itself.