# PPT/Word files is not downloading from IIS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ms-word, powerpoint

I have developed MVC4 application and hosted on IIS server.
In application i have created templates for PPT and Word to download.
 It's perfectly worked on local but after hosting on IIS server i am not able to download it.
Kindly provide me solution & which setting its requires on Component Services of server or other things.
 My code is :
**Controller :**

```
 public ActionResult DownloadFile(GlobalDashboardModel objGlobalDashboard)
 {
    //string contentType = "application/doc";
     objBSS = new BSS_Repository();

    var currentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now).ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
    object temporaryFileName = Server.MapPath(_tempPathOnServer) + "GloablDashboard" + "-" + currentDate + ".doc";

   string tempPathOnClient = _tempPathOnClient + "GloablDashboard" + "-" + currentDate + ".doc";

    MSWord.Document document = null;
    try
    {
          // processing for word document
          object missing = Missing.Value;

           MSWord.Application wordApp = new MSWord.Application();
           string templateFile = Server.MapPath(_globalDashboardTemplateFilePath);

            // copy from template file to temporary file
            System.IO.File.Copy(templateFile, (string)temporaryFileName, true);

             if (System.IO.File.Exists(temporaryFileName.ToString()))
             {
                 object readOnly = false;

                  object isVisible = false;

                  document = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref temporaryFileName, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                  document.Activate();

                   ////  Call FindAndReplace()function for each change
                   this.FindAndReplace(document, "<bsc>", objGlobalDashboard.bscCount);
                   this.FindAndReplace(document, "<bts>", objGlobalDashboard.btsCount);
                   this.FindAndReplace(document, "<nw>", objGlobalDashboard.networkAvailability);

                    ////  save temp.doc after modified
                    document.Save();
               }
                 return Json(new { path = tempPathOnClient }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   
                }
                catch
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "File does not exist !!!");
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (document != null)
                    {
                        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document)document).Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                    }
                }
          return Json(new { path = tempPathOnClient }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   
       }
```

Comment: How does your code look? What is the actual error? What have you tried?

Comment: I have a form in my application and i want it in word file, for that i have created a template and writes values in template by using interop.word library and download it by loation.href.Now hosted the application on iis server. This functionality is not working.

Comment: You need to post some code! What is the value for `location.href`?

Comment: Why `return Json()` - what's that trying to achieve, passing the filename but not the contents? Why not `return File()`?

Comment: I have used $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/DownloadFile/",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ objGlobalDashboard: objGlobalDashboard }),
        success: function (data) {
            window.location.href = data.path;
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log("Error in Export to Word");
        }

Comment: This is perfectly worked on local server. But after hosting on IIS Server (on another pc). then its not working. I think not able to access ms word but i don't no reason.

Comment: Oh, OK, so you're not actually trying to download the files: you're writing them to a shared server and then redirecting the client to a file share it can read them from? Does the IIS server have permission to write files to that path from the application pool, does it have word installed? In general you're advised against office automation from IIS - there's a KB article somewhere about that.

Comment: yes. Word is installed and same thing i am doing with csv & excel and its working but failed in case of word and ppt :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna make a bold assumption: the problem is not that you're unable to download the file. The problem is that your word automation doesn't run on the server. I've done server side word automation and your implementation is - to put it lightly - optimistic.

When you run your application on your local workstation, it runs with your user rights. On the server it runs with very restricted rights. The webuser account doesn't have DCOM rights for example. I gave a short rundown what to do configuration-wise here: [editing word document in c# asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032201/editing-word-document-in-c-sharp-asp-net/25377922#25377922)

As it is right now, your implementation will probably very much run into a `NullReferenceException` on the server. If it doesn't run into an Interop-related exception first. It very likely suffers from a memory leak as well. I strongly suggest that you implement some logging in your application before doing anything else. With that you would have known what the actual problem is.

Also you shouldn't use server-side word automation at all unless you **absolutely** have to. You may want to check if the OpenXML SDK fulfills your requirements as well. If you have to use it it's imperative to run load tests on the server with a memory profiler attached to spot memory leaks.